# about a,b=1,2 or a,b=[1,2] on ruby

Tags: ruby

```
a,b=1,2
=>[1,2]
a,b=[1,2]
=>[1,2]
```

i newbie on ruby,i have alchknowlege of python in python there also have this feature

what dose this feaure called in ruby,and also i have one thing confused

why after given the value to the a,b varient,the output a array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same, try this in IRB:

```
a,b=1,2
a.kind_of? Integer --> True
b.kind_of? Integer --> True
a.kind_of? Array --> False
b.kind_of? Array --> False
puts a --> 1
puts b --> 2

a,b=[1,2]
a.kind_of? Integer --> True
b.kind_of? Integer --> True
a.kind_of? Array --> False
b.kind_of? Array --> False
puts a --> 1
puts b --> 2
```

[Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) is your best friend + IRB ofcourse. There are many [good tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=ruby+tutorial) out there, choose one which suits you.

Comment: Good answer. Can you also help the questioner by referring to some book or tutorial.